# requireJS and ImagesLoaded : Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have kind of the same problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295459/requirejs-with-jquery-masonry-imagesloaded-object-object-object-has-no-me) but there seem to be no right answer.

I'm trying to load the "loadImages" lib with require.js but I get this

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded'

Here is the script on my page :

```
require(['./js/common'], function(common) 
{
    require(['home/main-home']);
});
```

My common.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './js',
    paths: {
        jquery : 'libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min',


        eventie  : 'libs/eventie/eventie',
        eventEmitter  : 'libs/eventEmitter/eventEmitter.min',
        imagesLoaded  : 'libs/imagesLoaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min',

        masonry  : 'libs/masonry/masonry.pkgd.min',
        wall : './wall/wall',
        underscore  : '../libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone : '../libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    },
    shim: {

        jquery : {
            exports : '$'
        },

        imagesLoaded : {
            deps : ['jquery', 'eventie', 'eventEmitter']
        },

        masonry : ['jquery'],
        wall : ['masonry', 'imagesLoaded'],

        backbone : {
            deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports : 'Backbone'
        },

        underscore : {
            exports : '_'
        }

    }
});
```

and this is my main-home.js where I want to use the imagesLoaded lib.

```
define([
  'wall'
], 
function(Wall){

  $(function() 
  {
      $('#photos').imagesLoaded( function(){}); // ERROR
  });

  return true;
});
```

In the imagesLoaded doc there's a small paragrah about require.js which i don't really understand. I tried to load thoses libs as well, but it is not changing anything.

```
// Install imagesLoaded and its dependencies
// Update your RequireJS paths config so it can find those modules
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    "eventie": "bower_components/eventie",
    "eventEmitter": "bower_components/eventEmitter"
  }
});
```

They seem to talk about it in here https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/68, but I don't really know what to do.

Here is the js files my page is loading :

[image]

We can see that imagesLoaded is loaded... 
**How come do I still have this error then ?**

Comment: Can you show which JS files are actually loaded by your page? E.g. proof that `libs/imagesLoaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min` is loaded?

Comment: Taking a look at the GitHub issue, it seems the script is not build correctly for AMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This jsfiddle works](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/utWXa/21/).

I've edited the ImagesLoaded JS ([as a gist](https://gist.github.com/gitgrimbo/6451492)) to give the modules a valid module id.

Search for:

```
// --------------------------------------------------
// ADDED A MODULE ID
// --------------------------------------------------
```

in the code for the 3 changes (to define the `imagesLoaded`, `eventEmitter/EventEmitter` and `eventie/eventie` modules).

Given that the ImageLoaded JS file already includes the other 2 modules, there is no need for any more paths/shims.

#### HTML

```
<div id="photos"></div>
<script>
require = {
    paths: {
        "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3",
        "imagesLoaded": "https://rawgithub.com/gitgrimbo/6451492/raw/f26e23d7a180ee23fd3dea3b0b152dbf523854a1/ImageLoaded-mod"
    }
};
</script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.8/comments/require.js"></script>
```

#### JS

```
require(["jquery", "imagesLoaded"], function($, imagesLoaded) {
    console.log($.fn.jquery);
    console.log(imagesLoaded);
    $('#photos').imagesLoaded(function() {
        console.log("something");
    });
});
```

#### Output

```
2.0.3
ImagesLoaded( elem, options, onAlways )
something
```